# The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>, Func<TFirst,

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Getting the error

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Zip(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicit

on

```
IEnumerable<Coordinate> perimeter = GetCoordinates(k, m, n);
IEnumerable<Coordinate> source = perimeter.Skip(r).Concat(perimeter.Take(r));
perimeter.Zip(source, (p, s) =>
{
    matrix[p.X, p.Y] = matrix[s.X, s.Y];
});
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing that it is not in line with the documentation I'm reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You have `Action` as last parameter instead of `Func`

Comment: The` Func<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>` must return an output of type `<TResult>` . your Func is not returning anything

Answer (score 3):

Zip has to return a result. If you don't need Zip to return anything, then you can add `return true;` to the anonymous function:

```
IEnumerable<Coordinate> perimeter = GetCoordinates(k, m, n);
IEnumerable<Coordinate> source = perimeter.Skip(r).Concat(perimeter.Take(r));
perimeter.Zip(source, (p, s) =>
{
    matrix[p.X, p.Y] = matrix[s.X, s.Y];
    return true;
});
```

Comment: you could use foreach statement on Zip returning anonymous variable.